# Beautiful soup webscrape into mysql

Tags: python, mysql

The code so far downloads and prints onto the screen,but how do I get that printed material into a sql database.If I wanted to get the data into CSV files it seems that Python(on a good day) creates the file automatically.Obviously with transferring into mySql I assume that I would have to create a database beforehand in order to receive the data.My question is how would I get the data from the scrape into the database omitting the csv step altogether.
In anticipation I have already downloaded pyMySql library.Any suggestions much aprreciated..looknow

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-      chart/19800203/7501/" )

 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div" , {"class" : "artist",})
 for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())

 html = urlopen("http://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-    chart/19800203/7501/" )
 bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
 nameList = bsObj. findAll("div" , {"class" : "title"})
 for name in nameList:
 print(name. get_text())
```

Answer (score 4):

So there are a couple things to address here.

The [docs on PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL#example) are pretty good at getting you up and running.

Before you can put these things into a database though, you need to grab them in a way that the artist and song name are associated with each other. Right now you are getting a separate list of artists and songs, with no way to associate them. You will want to iterate over the title-artist class to do this.

I would do this like so -

```py
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql.cursors

# Webpage connection
html = urlopen("http://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/19800203/7501/")

# Grab title-artist classes and iterate
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
recordList = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class" : "title-artist",})

# Now iterate over recordList to grab title and artist
for record in recordList:
     title = record.find("div", {"class": "title",}).get_text().strip()
     artist = record.find("div", {"class": "artist"}).get_text().strip()
     print artist + ': ' + title
```

This will print the title and artist for each iteration of the recordList loop.

To insert these values into a MySQL DB, I created a table called `artist_song` with the following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `artist_song` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `artist` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `song` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
  AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

This isn't the cleanest way to go about this, but the idea is sound. We want to open a connection to the MySQL DB (I have called my DB top_40), and insert an artist/title pair for each iteration of the recordList loop:

```py
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql.cursors


# Webpage connection
html = urlopen("http://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/19800203/7501/")

# Grab title-artist classes and store in recordList
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
recordList = bsObj.findAll("div", {"class" : "title-artist",})

# Create a pymysql cursor and iterate over each title-artist record.
# This will create an INSERT statement for each artist/pair, then commit
# the transaction after reaching the end of the list. pymysql does not
# have autocommit enabled by default. After committing it will close
# the database connection.
# Create database connection

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='password',
                             db='top_40',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        for record in recordList:
            title = record.find("div", {"class": "title",}).get_text().strip()
            artist = record.find("div", {"class": "artist"}).get_text().strip()
            sql = "INSERT INTO `artist_song` (`artist`, `song`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (artist, title))
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Edit: 
Per my comment, I think it is clearer to iterate over the table rows instead:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql.cursors


# Webpage connection
html = urlopen("http://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/19800203/7501/")

bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

rows = bsObj.findAll('tr')
for row in rows:
    if row.find('span', {'class' : 'position'}):
        position = row.find('span', {'class' : 'position'}).get_text().strip()
        artist = row.find('div', {'class' : 'artist'}).get_text().strip()
        track = row.find('div', {'class' : 'title'}).get_text().strip()
```

Comment: hi rp372,thankyou for that very detailed reply,it works great!I have a problem however when I try and add another field(position).On line 11 I added -position.on line 32 I added..position = record.find("div", {"class": "position"}).get_text().strip()..and then added position to the other parts of the code where required plus adding an extra%s.In bothN++ and PyCharm I get the same message"invalid syntax Line 35".any suggestions much appreciated and thanks again for the help.

Comment: edit: not sure how to paste code in a comment.
It looks like position is not in the same div as artist or title. I would actually try iterating over the rows of the table. This seems to work better for me:

    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)
    rows = bsObj.findAll('tr')
    for row in rows:
        if row.find('span', {'class' : 'position'}):
            position = row.find('span', {'class' : 'position'}).get_text().strip()
            artist = row.find('div', {'class' : 'artist'}).get_text().strip()
            track = row.find('div', {'class' : 'title'}).get_text().strip()